# Why do I need Windows Server Connector?

Tags: windows, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

I am replacing a Windows Server 2003 server with Windows Server 2012 Essentials.  The migration guide advises me to run the Windows Server Connector software on every domain-joined computer, unless they are Vista or older.  Is this software necessary?  What benefits does it get me?

Comment: Essentials is meant for a home environment. Is that what you're using it for? The Connector installs an agent that lets you monitor the client and manage the server.

Comment: @NathanC - Not to pick nits, but Windows Server 2012 Essentials is the replacement for Windows Small Business Server 2011. It's definitely business-oriented.

Comment: I am using it for a small office network.